# Can abstract ViewModel class can be injected by HIlt?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have a BaseViewModel class.

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    abstract fun sendLog(msg: String)
}
```

And now I need to inherit this in all the ViewModels. It's a lot of work.
I just want to implement once and use it in other ViewModels too.

So, Can I do this like this?

```
@HiltViewModel
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    @Inject construct(logger: Logger)
    open fun sendLog(msg: String){
        viewModelScope.launch{
            logger.callApi(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

or is there any better way???

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have only one instance of Logger, so that you can get it lazyly. With a bit of Kotlins syntactic sugar and the ability to set a body for interface methods you can do something like this:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

class Logger {
    fun log(text: String) = println(text)
}

interface Foo {
    fun ViewModel.logSomething(msg: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            logger.log(msg)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @Inject
        lateinit var logger: Logger
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
open class BaseViewModel : ViewModel(), Foo

class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
    init {
        logSomething("That's a test")
    }
}
```

If that doesn't fit your needs feel free to comment below